# C program to get variable name as input and print value

Tags: c, gcc

I have a program test.c

```
int global_var=10;
printf("Done");
```

i did

```
gcc -g test.c -o test
```

My query is 
Is there a way i can get the variable name as argument (say "global_var") and print the value.

Thanks

Comment: Don't name your executable `test` since it is often a shell builtin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to access at runtime global variables by name. Sometimes, it might depend upon the operating system, and how the compiler is invoked. I still assume you want to dereference a global variable, and you know its type.

Then on Linux and some other systems, you could use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with a `NULL` path (to get a handle for the executable), then use `dlsym` on the global variable name to get its address; you can then cast that `void*` pointer to a pointer of the appropriate type and dereference it. Notice that you need to know the type (or at least have a convention to encode the type of the variable in its name; C++ is doing that with [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)). If you compiled and linked with debug information (i.e. with `gcc -g`) the type information is in its [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) sections of your [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable, so there is some way to get it.

This works if you link your executable using `-rdynamic` and with `-ldl`

Another possibility might be to customize your recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with your own [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension which would remember and later re-use some of the compiler internal representations (i.e. the [GCC *Tree*-s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) related to global variables). Use MELT `register_finish_decl_first` function to register a handler on declarations. But this will require some work (in coding your MELT extension).

---

#### using preprocessor tricks

You could use (portable) preprocessor tricks to achieve your goals (accessing variable by name at runtime).

The simplest way might be to define and follow your own conventions. For example you could have your own `globvar.def` header file containing just lines like

```
 /* file globvar.def */
 MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE(globalint,int)
 MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE(globalint2,int)
 MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE(globalstr,char*)
 #undef MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE
```

And you adopt the convention that all global variables are in the above `globvar.def` file. Then you would `#include "globvar.def"` *several times*. For instance, in your global header, expand `MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE` to some `extern` declaration:

```
 /* in yourheader.h */
 #define MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE(Nam,Typ) extern Typ Nam;
 #include "globvar.def"
```

In your `main.c` you'll need a similar trick to *declare* your globals.

Elsewhere you might define a function to get integer variables by name:

```
 /* return the address of  global int variable or else NULL */
 int* global_int_var_by_name (const char*name) {
    #define MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE(Nam,Typ) \
      if (!strcmp(#Typ,"int") && !strcmp(name,#Nam)) return (int*)&Nam;
    #include "globvar.def"
      return NULL;
 }
```

etc etc...  I'm using [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) of macro arguments.

Such preprocessor tricks are purely standard C and would work with any C99 compliant compiler.

Answer (score 3):

No, C doesn't have [introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection_%28computer_science%29). Once the compiler has generated code, the program can not look up variable names.

The way these things are usually solved is by having a collection of all special variables that needs to be looked up by name, containing both the actual name as a string and the variable it self.

Usually it's an array of structures, something like

```
struct
{
    const char *name;
    int value;
} variables[] = {
    { "global_var", 10 }
};
```

The program can then look through the array `variables` to search for `"global_var"` and use (or change) the value in the structure.

Answer (score 2):

No.
We only have variable names so humans don't get confused .
After your program gets turned into assembly and eventually machine code, the computer doesn't care what you name your variables.

Alternatively you could use a structure in which you would store the value and the name as a string:

```
struct tag_name {
   char *member1;
   int member2;
};
```

Comment: I think you're programming to much Java or something, that's not valid C.

Comment: Please explain why. Thanks. Not that this is just the definition of a structure not the actual initialization of one.

Comment: JoachimPileborg means, would your code compile in standard `C`?

Comment: Well you can't initialize a structure inline like you do, and arrays are not declared the way you do.

Answer (score 2):

General answer: No. There is no connection between a variable name and its string representation (you can get the string representation of a variable name at compile time with the preprocessor, though).

For identifiers with external linkage, there are (platform-dependent) ways: See e.g. `dlsym` for POSIX systems.

You can compile with debugging information and access (most) variables by names from input. Unless you really write something like a debugger, this would be a horrible design, however (and even then, you don’t access the variables used in the debugger itself but of the programme being debugged).

Finally, you could implement your own lookup table mapping from string representations to values.