# Why #include<.hpp> in .cpp, not <.cpp> in .hpp?

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor, header-files

**I wonder why recommended way is to `#include<example.hpp>` in `example.cpp`**; I don't understand, how preprocessor (which seems to be quite simple program) knows that definition of methods are in `example.cpp` - name of this file isn't appear in `main.cpp` and in included file `example.hpp`. AFAIK, `#include<filename>` is simply replaced using `filename`'s content.

I always invert the situation - I `#include<example.cpp>` in `example.hpp`. Then, preprocessor, while including `example.hpp` includes also `example.cpp`.

Comment: Hope that works out for you when you start violating the One Definition Rule.

Comment: You won't be able to reuse the `example.hpp` anywhere else besides your `main.cpp` if you include the corresponding source there. Stop that nonsense please! Immediately!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files-in-c?lq=1

Comment: This question shows a misunderstanding of how the C++ compilation process works. It's a completely reasonable misunderstanding though, so I'm not sure why the downvotes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He's not asking about a problem in any specific piece of code, so an MCVE makes no sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `#include` arbitrary files in a C++ translation unit (the `*.cpp` you are compiling) provided the preprocessed form (after pre-processing) is valid C++. Read some documentation on the [preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) and the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) wikipage. Don't forget that preprocessing is the first phase in a C or C++ compiler. (Historically, it was even a different process `/lib/cpp`; now it is inside the compiler for performance reasons).

The name of the included file does not matter much. Conventionally, you don't want to name an included file to look like a top-level translation unit. This is why people generally do not `#include "example.cpp"`  but something like e.g. `#include "example.inc"` or `#include "example-inc.cpp"` (or `#include "example.def"`, specially if you `#include` *several times* a header). The standard C++ library accepts [`#include <map>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/) for example.

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25198583/841108) which shows some included file which is `#include`-d *several times* (for different purposes), or, inside the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) source tree, the [file `gcc/tree.def`](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/tree.def?view=markup)

Of course, you cannot `#include` several times an *arbitrary* C++ file in the same compilation unit (because you cannot have several definitions of e.g. the same function).

In practice, use e.g. `g++ -C -E foo.cc > foo.ii` to get the pre-processed form of translation unit `foo.cc` ... then look with a pager or editor into the preprocessed form `foo.ii`

Read also about [some proposal on modules in C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3347.pdf). It was not accepted in the latest C++ standard, but something similar might *perhaps* become standardized in the future.